# Why enabling _only_ TLSv1.3 is a bad idea?

Tags: nginx, security

I have NGINX configured to only support TLS version 1.3
However when I go to https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/

It shows the error

Error creating a TLS-Connection: TLSv1.3 found, but no connection via TLSv1.2 possible. Please activate TLSv1.2

Isn't enabling only TLSv1.3 much safer? Why do we still need to enable TLSv1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS 1.3 only, is possible with modern clients. Test with the oldest client version you will support for your users.

[Mozilla's server TLS profiles](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) and configuration generator remains a good resource.

Comment: Yeah, I guess SSL Labs is buggy then. A server that _only_ supports TLSv1.3 only gets an A, while a server that supports both TLSv1.3 and TLSv1.2 gets a A+

Answer (score 0):

As of 13th March 2024, browser support for TLS 1.3 is 96.41%.

Browser support for TLS 1.2 is  97.96%

I think it is a bad idea not to support TSL 1.2, while I have just discovered [www.ecb.europa.eu](http://www.ecb.europa.eu) stopped supporting TSL 1.2 that caused the error in our download client, which I think is a bad idea, as more than 1% of internet browsers do not support TSL 1.3 at this moment.